# Problem with sending email in django using SMTP with new google rules

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am using smtp to send emails in django app but for some reasons it stops working and i found this on the google page.
[image: info found on google page]

I do not want to use SendGrid or others.because in my app i send more than 1000000 emails per semester and it was working well before this new condition.
How can i solve this problem ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create an application token in the Google account you use to send the emails with and use it instead of your usual email password.

Have a look at this link: [Authorizing Your App with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth)

Comment: Thank you i first activated double authentification,after that i created an app password and instead of my gmail password i used the app password,